# Where is the selection tool for the WPF designer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm stuck on crosshairs and can't figure out how to get to an arrow cursor so I can select items on the design surface. I think there used to be a white arrow at the top of every category in the Toolbox, but that doesn't seem to be available in VS 2010.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. Turns, out I needed to reset my toolbox. I think Blend may have done something weird to it.

Comment: I had the same thing though I hadn't used Blender but resetting worked fine, thanks!